# Gpfit error on line 74. Not even working with the given matlab example

Tags: matlab, distribution

It appears that upgrading matlab to 2016a made no difference to my problem and once again, I cannot even perform the matlab example using the gpfit function. I get the following error when using the Matlab code online:

```
y =
      0.0017    7.2773

Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to
logical scalar values.

Error in gpfit (line 74)

if n == 0 || ~isfinite(rangex)
```

and the function keeps spitting y out as the minimum and maximum (rangex). My data is too big to attach and I do not think it is worth it to scale down as it is really just a matrix of wind speeds. No Nans no Infs.

When I add a breakpoint to the gpfit code, I can see that n is scalar 1x1 so I am pretty confused!

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What dimension is your first input? It should be either a row or column vector otherwise `range` returns a multi-element array (range for each column) rather than a  scalar and the `isfinite` will result in a non-scalar which obviously can't be conbined with the scalar `n == 0`. Try calling `gpfit(x(:))`. It would also be helpful to link to this example you speak of.

Comment: The input is a 465x1 double. I still cannot figure out why it won't work with the matlab example however. That suggests that it is nothing to do with the data no?

Comment: What does `which range` yield?

Comment: this path: /data2/mia35/Documents/Matlab/nctoolbox-1.1.0/demos/contrib/range.m

Comment: That's the problem. Someone created a `range.m` which is being used instead of the builtin. Either delete or rename it. Also slap the developer on the wrist

Comment: I had this issue with wblfit as well and I just for the life of me cannot remember how I solved it.

Comment: Basically, DO NOT name anything as MATLAB fucntions.

Comment: Yes, it seems that the nctoolbox messed up there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you have a file named `range.m` on your file path which must return a multi-element array. This is an issue because the built-in [`range`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/range.html) function returns a scalar value (given a vector input).

> range(X) returns the difference between the maximum and the minimum of a sample. For vectors, range(x) is the range of the elements. For matrices, range(X) is a row vector containing the range of each column of X. For N-dimensional arrays, range operates along the first nonsingleton dimension of X.

Within the `gpfit` function, there are the following lines:

```
n = length(x);
x = sort(x(:));
xmax = x(end);
rangex = range(x);

if n == 0 || ~isfinite(rangex)
```

If  we look at this, obviously the dimensions of `x` can't be the issue since those are forced to be a column vector: `sort(x(:))`. And also, `n` is guaranteed to be a scalar. If `range` is called properly it should *also* be a scalar.

In order to use `||` in MATLAB, you must be comparing two *scalars*. Because the `range.m` that exists on your path provides an *array* rather than a scalar, this causes the `||` to fail since `n == 0` is obviously a scalar but `isfinite(rangex)` is **not**.

You want to first identify which `range.m` exists on your path:

```
which('range')
```

Then you will want to rename it or remove the containing folder from your search path.

### Important Lessons

In general, it is bad practice to name a variable or function the same as a built-in as this can cause this sort of odd and difficult to track-down issue. One easy way to prevent this from happening is to not blindly add folders to your MATLAB search path. As strange as it is, MATLAB's own built-in functions will use your custom function rather than the other built-in functions if they are higher on the search path (I've never understood this behavior but it is what it is).

Comment: Done and worked! Thank you very much sir. Cured a big and annoying issue.

Comment: @user2013373 Not a problem. I updated my answer with a little more info to hopefully prevent these sorts of things in the future

Comment: Thank you so much Suever. Massive help and insight! All makes sense now. The prevention of blind adding to the path is a very useful tip!